# How to differentiate between text and formula in JLatexMathView

Tags: java, android

I am creating an android app with JAVA in which I will provide questions realted maths and physics. I have used JLatexMathView to show formula in proper form. It is working fine . But the problem here is that I have added questions in database in mixed form like this " Find the value of [formula]" that's why when it is being loaded in mathiew it is showing like this "Findthevalueof[formula]" . It is treating the text as formula and erasing the space between the words.

I want to show it separately like a normal question. How can I do this please explain.
Please let me know if there is any other option to do this.
I am providing some of my codes below

XML code

````
   <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout        


   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">
    

    <ru.noties.jlatexmath.JLatexMathView
        android:id="@+id/j_latex_math_view"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:padding="16dip"
        app:jlmv_alignHorizontal="center"
        app:jlmv_alignVertical="center"
        app:jlmv_textSize="16sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>```




JAVA code
````

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

MathView mathView ;
 JLatexMathView latex;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    latex = findViewById(R.id.j_latex_math_view);


    final JLatexMathDrawable drawable = JLatexMathDrawable.builder(" Find value of  \\[\\sqrt[n]   {ab}\\overleftarrow{ab}\\coprod_a^b\\left(\\begin{array}{c}a\\\\    b\\end{array}\\right)\\sum_a^b\\]\n")
            .textSize(70)
            .padding(8)
            .background(0xFFffffff)
            .align(JLatexMathDrawable.ALIGN_RIGHT)
            .build();



    latex.setLatex(" hhhhhhh bbbbbbbbbbbb bbbbbbbbbbb tttttttt \\[\\sqrt[n]{ab}\\overleftarrow{ab}\\coprod_a^b\\left(\\begin{array}{c}a\\\\ b\\end{array}\\right)\\sum_a^b\\]\n");
  //  latex.setLatexDrawable(drawable);
}
```

```
DEENDENCY 

    implementation 'ru.noties:jlatexmath-android:0.2.0'

// for Cyrillic symbols
    implementation 'ru.noties:jlatexmath-android-font-cyrillic:0.2.0'

// for Greek symbols
    implementation 'ru.noties:jlatexmath-android-font-greek:0.2.0'

I tried to show mixed text + formula questions for maths and physics android
```